# Trying to increase the default stack size of IIS on Windows Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6

I'm currently running an ASP.NET WebForms application on Windows Server 2008 running IIS 6.2, and I've started getting the following error message:

`System.InsufficientExecutionStackException: Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely. This can happen from having too many functions on the call stack or function on the stack using too much stack space. at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.EnsureSufficientExecutionStack() at System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl(String id, Int32 pathOffset)`

I've spent hours trying to fix the issue, and found a common solution, modifying w3wp.exe to increase the default stack size from 256kb to 1MB using the following command line:

> EDITBIN /STACK:1048576 w3wp.exe

But when I try and run it using the following steps:

- Open CMD as administrator
- Type cd C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv
- Then type EDITBIN /STACK:1048576 w3wp.exe

I get the following message:

> 'EDITBIN' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Is somebody able to point me in the right direction as to why the command isn't working?

Comment: this is more likely to be a problem with your code... recursive loop?  Look through your calls to "FindControl"

Comment: Hi @pcalkins, there's a fair few of them on the page. I can look into replacing the FindControl function and generating values via the stored procedure instead.

Answer (score 0):

Editbin.exe depend on Developer Command Prompt for Visual studio.  So you have to install visual studio first.
Then you will see this

[image]

Run it as administrator, then you will be able to use your command line directly.
[image]

If the command line is not working, it is recommended to collect and analyze call stack with debug diagnostic tool collection and analysis tool.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924